# Why is hibernate-java8 (hibernate 5.x) jar shown deprecated?

Tags: java-8, deprecated, hibernate-5.x

Hibernate 5 and above supports Java8 DateTime Api through jar "hibernate-java8".
But the MavenRepository shows a message Deprecated - use hibernate-core instead) alongside the title of the hibernate-java8 jar.
Why is the hibernate-java8 jar called deprecated even though it is required to gain the hibernate support for java8?
 [image: maven repository hibernate-java8]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can see the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guide---5.2) for Hibernate. It specifies that

> Hibernate 5.2 is built using Java 8 JDK and will require Java 8 JRE at
>   runtime (we are investigating whether Java 9 will also work). This has
>   a number of implications:
>
> The hibernate-java8 module has been merged into hibernate-core and the
>   Java 8 date/time types are now natively supported.
>
> (todo) support for Java 8 Optional
>
> (todo) support for other Java 8 features?

The hibernate-java8 module has been removed; that functionality has been consolidated into hibernate-core.

For [hibernate-java8](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844) see this ticket for explanation,

> As this relies on Java 8 and Hibernate still maintains compatibility
>   back to Java 6, a new module hibernate-java8 was added to isolate the
>   Java 8 compatibility to just these classes. We will fold the classes
>   from this module into hibernate-core once we baseline one Java 8.

Since hibernate no longer maintains the hibernate-java8 and you can see that hibernate-java8 is nothing more than an empty placeholder. [Github](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-java8/src/main/resources) & [JIRA Detail](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10883).

So, As the functionality has been merged into hibernate-core; hibernate-java8 now is depreciated.

I hope this answer your queries.