# Type mismatch: number, date or string expected hibernate LocalDate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mismatch

Task:

---

The field `dates` has type `date` in the **database**.

```sql
create table items
(
    id   serial primary key,
    dates date
);
```

**Entity**: // field "date" , type "LocalDate":

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item {
    private LocalDate date;

    @Column(name = "dates")
    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

**class UserStore:**

```java
class UserStore {
    private final SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
            .configure().buildSessionFactory();

    public List<?> findByDate() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        final String sql = "from Item i where i.date between ?1 and ?2";
        Query query = session.createQuery(sql, Item.class);
        query.setParameter(1, LocalDate.now());
        query.setParameter(2, LocalDate.now());
        List<?> result = query.getResultList();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

added:

```
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
```

in the sql request: "from Item i where **i.date** between ?1 and ?2",
field **i.date** is highlighted in red, indicating a **jpa error** and requiring the use of the Date type:

[image: to look a mistake]

If i use type `Date` instead `LocalDate` mistake escape. But I need `LocalDate` type.

---

**How to fix it?**

> ps. The code compiles correctly.code implementation is not important. question one: How to remove the error without turning off the inspection.

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: @SternK Hi.    .PostgreSQL9Dialect

Comment: Hi Mailtime, concerning something you asked elsehwere: Do you know that you can sort the view of answers to a question by age, votes and activity? It is the reason why for example "above answer" is usually an ambiguous reference.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `hibernate-java8` artifact from your `pom.xml`. It is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761619/why-is-hibernate-java8-hibernate-5-x-jar-shown-deprecated). The `hibernate-core` will be enough. I have tested your query and it works fine for me with `LocalDate`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Proposed changes have made, but it does not work for me.